# Multiple values in ngClass

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a controller which gives me the right value for my actions. The possible values are 1, 2, 3, 4. I have checked this and works fine. I created a class, which will only be active when the value is 1. This works perfectly. But i like to class not only to be set for the value 1, but also for 3 and 4. I thought this would be pretty easy, but i cannot figure it out. I post my current expression, and what i tried. Hopefully one of you can help me.

Works fine, also if i change 1 to 3 (but ofcourse it reacts only on 3 then)

```
ng-class="{thumbdarken: thumb.isSet(1)}"
```

This is what i would like to have working

```
ng-class="{thumbdarken: thumb.isSet(1 || 3 || 4)}"
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably make three function calls each with different parameter, rather than a single function call (because `1 || 3 || 4` will always evaluate to `1`, meaning you'd be always checking for `thumb.isSet(1)`). So, do something like this:

```
ng-class="{thumbdarken: ( thumb.isSet(1) || thumb.isSet(3) || thumb.isSet(4) )}"
```

Comment: Yes youre right. Works perfectly. Maybe i have to goto bed, now i read this answer, i should have thought of that myself. Thanks very much!